# Workflow - sms/email notifications

Tags: workflows, notifications

Is there a way to set up sms/email notifications to be sent out to site users responsible for each workflow stage? Also, is there a way of automatically "assigning" a node to the correct resource for managing the workflow stage?

Comment: Which modules are you using for workflow? Rules? Workbench? Moderation? And for which version of Drupal?

Comment: I am using drupal 7 @choster

Also, I am using the workflow module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the rules module. You can set up a rule that accesses other module (search for a sms module), or core features (like mail).